# unindent does not match any outer indentation level pytube

Tags: download, youtube, pytube

unfile('C:/Users/ttcho/Desktop/1234.py', wdir='C:/Users/ttcho/Desktop')
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 132
cipher_url = [ parse_qs(formats[i]["signatureCipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats) ] except Exception: cipher_url = [ parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats) ]

cipher_url = [ parse_qs(formats[i]["signatureCipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats) ] except Exception: cipher_url = [ parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats) ]

does anyone can help me how to fix it? please

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please clarify.

Comment: I want to download video from YouTube, and the error showed that unfile('C:/Users/ttcho/Desktop/1234.py', wdir='C:/Users/ttcho/Desktop') File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 132 cipher_url = [ parse_qs(formats[i]["signatureCipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats) ] except Exception: cipher_url = [ parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats) ] I want to know how to fix it